# Populating a nested class with "outer join" using linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to populate class A (sorry for bad naming), with data from EF using Linq.

Got these classes:

```
public class A
{
    public string SomeA { get; set; }
    public B B { get; set; }
    public List<C> C { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public string SomeB { get; set; }
    public string SomeB2 { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public string SomeC { get; set; }
    public string SomeC2 { get; set; }
}
```

My SQL query to get all info needed looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM A
    JOIN B ON A.X = B.X
    LEFT JOIN C ON C.X = B.X
```

How would the linq query look like to populate A?

```
List<A> things = ......
```

Thanks in advance

/Lasse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easier than you might expect:

```
List<A> things = (
    from thing in db.As
    where thing.B.C != null
    select thing)
    .ToList();
```

*Note: for this to work, your EF model must understand there is a FK relationship between `B` and `C`. When that's the case (which will normally be when that FK is in the database and you generated your model directly from the database definition), EF will generate the `C` property on `B` (and vice versa).*

Comment: How would this look if I needed to "select new"?

Comment: The same, but with `select new` :-). Something like `from thing in db.As select new { Some = thing.B.C.SomeC }`.